# Athena still refers to old schema after updating the schema in the glue data catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a JSON file that has spaces in the field names. The Glue crawler is able to infer it and create the fields appropriately in a struct. But when I query this table in Athena I get the HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR complaining about the space in the field name. So I updated the table manually in the glue data catalog to get rid of spaces in the column names. When I go to Athena after the update and do a generate DDL I get the right columns without spaces. However the select still fails with the HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR and it keeps telling me that I have spaces in the column names.

Anyone knows how to get around this problem? Changing the source data is not allowed

Comment: I can think of 2 possibilities. 1> There might be a column which still has spaces. 2> Refresh "Data" in Athena console. If thats not the case, provide full error message you received.